# null pointer exception when I refer to my custom class?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Because my log command kicks out a "4" I am guessing it is:

```
word.getnewword();
```

that is returning the null pointer exception, but why?

The aim of the code is to have a class that will hold different letters in a word for me to then animate each letter in the word separately then change the word to a random new one from a list in the class. I am using char for each letter instead of a string for the word or each letter, is that ok also?

```
package com.xyz.letters;

import ......abreviated



public class letters extends Activity {

private Animals word;
boolean gameover = false;
private AdView adView;

TextView tva;
TextView tvb;
TextView tvc;
TextView tvd;
TextView tve;
TextView tvf;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.letters);
    Log.e("main", "xml loaded fine"); 
    tva = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texta);
    tvb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textb);
    tvc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textc);
    tvd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textd);
    tve = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texte);
    tvf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textf);
    Log.e("main", "textview pre-setup complete"); 




    Log.e("main", "4"); 
        word.getnewword();  
        Log.e("main", "gotword " + word.getwordchosennumber());
        setletters();
        Log.e("main", "set letters ok");
......etc
```

My class:-

```
package com.xyz.letters;

import java.util.Random;

import android.util.Log;


public class Animals {

private int wordchosen;
private int length;
private char l1;
private char l2;
private char l3;
private char l4;
private char l5;
private char l6;


public Animals() {
    this.wordchosen = 0;
    this.length = 3;
    this.l1 = 'a';
    this.l2 = 'b';
    this.l3 = 'c';
    this.l4 = 'a';
    this.l5 = 'b';
    this.l6 = 'c';

}

public void getnewword() {
    Log.e("animals", "0");
       Random ran = new Random();
        Log.e("animals", "1");
       wordchosen = ran.nextInt(2); 
        Log.e("animals", "2");

   switch (wordchosen) {
        case 0:
            length = 3;
            l1 = 'a';
            l2 = 'n';
            l3 = 't';
            break;
        case 1:
            length = 4;
            l1 = 'b';
            l2 = 'a';
            l3 = 'l';
            l4 = 'l';
            break;
        case 2:
            length = 3;
            l1 = 'b';
            l2 = 'a';
            l3 = 't';
            break;


        default: 
            length = 0;
            break;
    }
}

public int getwordchosennumber()
{
    return this.wordchosen;
}

public int getlength()
{
    return this.length;
}

public int getl1()
{
    return this.l1;
}

public int getl2()
{
    return this.l2;
}

public int getl3()
{
    return this.l3;
}

public int getl4()
{
    return this.l4;
}

public int getl5()
{
    return this.l5;
}

public int getl6()
{
    return this.l6;
}
}
```

Comment: _LogCat_ trace please...

Comment: private Animals word;
`word = new Animals();`

Comment: yes @var__ is right where is `word = new Animals();` , it may the problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, `word` has `null` value. The exception `null pointer exception` itself specify its meaning that, you want to access some object, which has `null` reference.

Declared here

```
private Animals word;
```

Initially, it has `null` reference, until you won't do something like

```
word = new Animals();  // assign Animals reference
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `word`. On the line before the error (or in the initial declaration), use `new`:

```
word = new Animals(); // The line to insert.
word.getnewword();
```

On future questions, when you get an exception or force close, please post the full LogCat stack trace (red text in your log output), to help us find the problem quicker.

Answer (score 0):

In the OnCreate after 
    Log.e("main", "textview pre-setup complete");

add

```
word = new Animals();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the object of the class like

```
  word = new Animals();
```

now, use this object to access the public methods and variable of Animals class.

```
 word.getnewword();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a NullPointerException because the variable "word" wasn't initialized. Android is a little bit strange when it comes to working with variables. If you don't initialize the variable in the onCreate method (or some method that is called from the onCreate method) before you call the variable then you will get a NullPointerException because the JVM doesn't know what the value of that variable is. It's kind of like regular java code that has a main method - if you call a variable that hasn't been inialized in the main method you'll get a NullPointerException.

To fix your code simply put this in the onCreateMethod before you make any calls to the variable:

```
word = new Animals();
```

After that you can do what you need with the variable.